# How to add custom prompt inside custom grunt-init template

Tags: gruntjs

Potential n00b question, but google didnt have a nice succinct answer - lets fix that together.

I am starting out with grunt and I am stuck on something fundamental. I discovered grunt-init had been moved into a seperate process - the fragmentation around the documentation doesnt make this obvious at first, but thats cool.

I am now deciding i would like my own grunt-init template that sits in the root directory of my site (for now, until it becomes time to move it into the ~/.grunt-init dir). I am using grunt 0.3.17

And going through the grunt-init-jquery and other init templates - i notice they all use the standard init prompts.

I would like to create some custom prompts with information relevant to the client, perhaps add the client email, or project managers name.

But i can't for the life of me figure out how to create/where to store a custom prompt that can be called within grunt-init.

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 7):

---

**UPDATE: Feb 8 2012**

Tne answer it seems, lies within the `init.process` command.

Start up the process to begin prompting for input.
**init.process(options, prompts, done)**

```
    init.process({}, [
      // Prompt for these values
      init.prompt('name'),
      init.prompt('description'),
      init.prompt('version')
    ], function(err, props) {
      // All finished, do something with the properties
    });
```

Where the prompts argument is an array of objects. You can add your own without registering new helpers, or extending the prompt.

Custom prompts can be added like so:

```
    init.process({}, [

        // Prompt for these values.
        {
          name: 'client_name',
          message: 'Who is the client contact?',
          default: 'Joe Smith', 
          validator: /^[\w\-\.]+$/,
          warning: 'Must be only letters, numbers, dashes, dots or underscores. (If this is not for a client, say HOUSE)'
        },
        {
          name: 'project_manager',
          message: 'Who is the project manager?',
          default: 'Me', 
          validator: /^[\w\-\.]+$/,
          warning: 'Must be only letters, numbers, dashes, dots or underscores.'
        }


    ], function(err, props) {
      // All finished, do something with the properties
    });
```

Comment: I don't see underscores in your validation regexes.

Comment: You are right, that was a mashed together example of prompts rather than being something gospel to run in production.